# Is there a way to enable Visual-Assist-style tooltips for comments with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

One thing that I've found incredibly useful, especially when working with code that I haven't written myself, is when tooltips can show me the comments, and syntax highlighting for a given variable/value/function/method/etc. It wastes time having to go to the implementation itself to read the comments and then come back.

Visual Assist X for Visual Studio does this, here's an example I found:
[image: Visual Assist Tooltip]

Notice the comments at the bottom of the image, and syntax highlighting applied to the tooltip itself.

I'm hoping IntelliJ IDEA does this, or at least that a plugin for it does. Any help is much appreciated.

Background info: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 11, particularly for Scala.

Comment: For anyone else that would like syntax highlighting in tooltips, I've created a feature request for this on the JetBrains developers forums: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5449700#5449700

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> will show you ScalaDoc for the the thing you have under cursor. [More info](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-inline-documentation.html)

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to quickly view the definition of that thing. [More info](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-definition.html)

You can also find useful <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> - it shows parameter list for the function you are calling and your progress so far (in bold). I find it very helpful when I writing method calls. [More info](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-method-parameter-information.html)

---

In order to make it work, you need to attach sources and/or javadocs to you library dependencies. You can make in **module settings** (dependencies tab). Just double click on the library dependency and you will see options that allow you to attach sources and javadocs. They are normally distributed as JAR and ZIP files or you can also simply point them to some directory in you file system.

Comment: Is there a specific way that the code must be documented for this feature to work? When I use CTRL+Q all I get is the function definition, but no comments.
And, slightly off-topic: How do you get the images for keys to show up in your answer? :)

Comment: @NicFoster: I updated my answer. For the keys I write following:  `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>`.

Comment: thanks for the update. I'm not using actual library dependencies for the most part, it's all own our code, but there is a ton of code. So to clarify, I'm not seeing comments in the documentation from code in my own project when using Ctrl+Q.

Comment: @NicFoster: You need to follow scaladoc/javadoc conventions in order to see them : https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Syntax . This generally means that you need to add them just before definitions (of classes, methods, fields) and they should look like this: `/** my javadoc */`

Comment: Ah, perfect, now that is the answer I was looking for.